# Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Can some one take a look at this and tell me why I am getting this error. I am trying to pull a table from a Mysql database and print it to a text file. I gives me the error listed above.

```
package db;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TableToTextFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<int[]> data = new ArrayList();

        try {
            Connection con = null;
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "root");
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("Select * from employee");

            while (rs.next()) {
                String id = rs.getString("emp_id");
                String name = rs.getString("emp_name");
                String address = rs.getString("emp_address");
                String contactNo = rs.getString("contactNo");
                data.add(id + " " + name + " " + address + " " + contactNo);

            }
            writeToFile(data, "Employee.txt");
            rs.close();
            st.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    private static void writeToFile(java.util.List list, String path) {
        BufferedWriter out = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(path);
            out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
            for (String s : list) {
                out.write(s);
                out.newLine();

            }
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly is the error occurring?  What are the data types of the table?

Comment: If the answers given still do not fix the problem, please tell us where the error occurs. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Possibly because your list has been declared to accept integer arrays and you're passing in a string.

```
List<int[]> data = new ArrayList();
```

Change it to accept strings instead.

```
List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
```

A much better and more object-oriented design would be to create a class called `Employee` and use it instead.

```
public class Employee {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    ...
}

List<Employee> data = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: How does it suppose to be releated to converting `Object` to `String`?